# Using Regex.Replace to safely escape hl7 control character

Tags: c#, regex, biztalk, hl7

After 2.5 hours trying to create a regex that will replace a Caret ^ to \S\, my last resort is to ask the community.

Example message:

```
OBX|1|SN|test one^example test one||^9||||||F
OBX|2|ST|test two^example test two||Critical||||||F
OBX|3|NM|test three^example test one||80|bpm|||||F
OBX|4|CE|1^Test Recorded||-3^U|ml|||||F
OBX|5|CE|2^Anchor||2^results||||||F
```

Requirement:
The carets in OBX-5 need replacing with \S\, but only when it is an OBX segment, and OBX-2 is of value type CE or SN. The reason for this is the the Biztalk HL7 dissassembler cannot handle carets in OBX-5, as it's not smart enough to know that if OBX-2 is of value type CE or SN, then OBX-5 has sub-types.

See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b73edde-575c-42c8-91ed-a9957f7b6d4f/biztalk-hl7-variable-datatypes-ex-obx5?forum=biztalkgeneral

The closest I got was using this regex:
`(?<=((OBX(\|))\d{1,4}(\|)(SN|CE)(\|)(((.+?)\|)(\|))))((\^))`

However, this does not work as I need to constrain it to OBX-5 only, and does not work for characters before the caret.

Apologies for the lengthy post! Appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Personally I'd write code to loop over those lines, check if the given line needs to have the carets replaced (maybe with a regex) and then do the replacement.  Trying to do everything in one regular expression is sometimes not worth the trouble.

Comment: why don't you modify HL7 schema to add more optional fields in OBX.5 field. it can easily be done without any code. Disassembler will then take those

Comment: i have decided to opt for a custom schema (I can't update the existing schema as it has 15+ interfaces using it). thanks for the advice both.

Comment: I'd like to remind the community that it is customary when downvoting to provide a comment explaining how the question might be improved.  These customs are especially important when working with brand new and inexperienced users.  Welcome (back?) to Stack Overflow, @LewisHoulden!

Answer (score 0):

Having had similar situations with inconsistent flat files...

I would use a custom Pipeline Component that reads the stream 'line' by 'line' and makes whatever changed you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. After much thought, it seemed like a *dirty* approach to use a custom pipeline component, as there are scenarios like, what about if an already escaped caret is included, what about if a target requires them unescaped? In the end, I've opted for a custom schema. Again, thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @LewisHoulden Oh, then for sure, customizing the Schema is the right way.  Very common actually.